# How to know if the image is fully loaded using Firebase and Angular 2

Tags: user-interface, angular, firebase, ionic2

I'm working on an Angular/Ionic hybrid mobile app, we use Firebase to store the images and their URLs, in the app's pages where there is pictures with different resolutions used, when they load for the first time, the text shows before the images (because texts < images, so they are faster to load) which causes an inconvenient UI/UX experience, is there any solution to show the page when everything is fully loaded, even the images?

Comment: It's hard to be sure without seeing the code that reproduces the problem, but you might be looking for this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/detect-when-images-are-loaded/20290

Comment: `<img src="{{ URL }}">`, this is a sample of **img** tag code written inside the html file (view) where the _URL_ is a variable which contains  the picture destination in Firebase in form of string inside the _.ts_ file (controller)